# The expectation values for the values of both qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

Let’s consider the two-qubit state
|Ψ⟩ =(1/2)|00⟩ + i(√3/4)|01⟩ +(3/4)|10⟩.
a) Find the expectation values for the values of both qubits separately.

Comment: Welcome to the Quantum Computing Stack Exchange. This is homework; you'll need to provide much more details as to what you've done and where you are stuck, otherwise most people will not be motivated to help. Edit your question by clicking on the "Edit" button next to the "Share" button to precisely explain what you understand and where you are most confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the single-qubit expectation values by tracing out the degrees of freedom of the other qubit. Mathematically, this corresponds to $\rho_A = \text{Tr}_B(|{\psi}_{AB}\rangle\langle{\psi_{AB}}|)$, if for a two-qubit system you want to know what happens to qubit $A$ only. The diagonal of the reduced density matrix gives you the new probabilities, so that $\text{Tr}(Z\rho_A)$ yields the expectation value of qubit $A$.

Another way to calculate this is to partition the global measurement outcomes, here the state $|{00}\rangle$ with probability $p_{00} = \frac{1}{4}$, state $|{01}\rangle$ with probability $p_{01} = \frac{3}{16}$ and state $|{10}\rangle$ with probability $p_{10} = \frac{9}{16}$, and add the probabilities of the states that have your qubit of interest in a certain state, ignoring whatever state the other qubit is in. For example, the probability that qubit 1 is in the 0-state is given by $p_{00}+p_{01}$, while the probability it is in the 1-state is given by $p_{10}$. In this case, the expectation value of qubit $A$ is $p_{00}+p_{01} - p_{10}.$

The two methods are equivalent.